# Xamarin forms: What is the correct format of RowDefinition height OnIdiom property?

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, rowdefinition

I have 2 rows inside a grid, for the first row has a fixed size. I am trying to apply the `OnIdiom` feature here. Tried like below:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition.Height>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                <OnIdiom.Phone>30</OnIdiom.Phone>
                <OnIdiom.Tablet>60</OnIdiom.Tablet>
            </OnIdiom>
        </RowDefinition.Height>
    </RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

But getting following error on error list:

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Height', or mismatching type between value and property.
```

What is the correct format of RowDefinition height OnIdiom property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`OnIdiom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#onidiom-markup-extension) markup extension:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{OnIdiom Phone=30, Tablet=60}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{OnIdiom Phone=30, Tablet=60}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="0"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </Grid>
```