# Xamarin Forms Grid RowDefinitions support OnIdiom on the same line as Grid is defined?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is a post on stack overflow which is very similar but doesn't actually ask about the new way of defining `RowDefinitions`. [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232820/xamarin-forms-what-is-the-correct-format-of-rowdefinition-height-onidiom-proper)

What is the correct format for `Idiom` using this row definition method...

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
      Margin="0, 10 ,0 ,10"
      RowDefinitions="{OnIdiom ?????}, *, 100">
</Grid>
```

Is it possible to set `Idiom` using inline property definitions or do I actually have to create `RowDefinitions` as shown in [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232820/xamarin-forms-what-is-the-correct-format-of-rowdefinition-height-onidiom-proper)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Platform Specific or Idiom Specific Row definitions there's only one way to do it through XAML,

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="{OnIdiom Phone=30, Tablet=60}" />
   <RowDefinition Height="{OnPlatform Android=40, iOS=35}" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's really unfortunate :(. My entire app is using that single-row definition. Oh well, I guess if that is the only way I gotta comply. Thanks for the answer I could not find anything was thinking I'm not searching correctly. Hope this can help others who might run into this issue and cant find the online answer.

Comment: It's fine the problem is that there is no way to directly do it in a single line because of OnPlatform and OnIdiom have multiple options it becomes really hard to perform String interpolation.